# boto3 Dynamodb table update is saving as objects instead of Number

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have this UpdateQUery in boto3

```
dynamo.update_item(
                    Table='table1',
                    Key={
                         'partition_key': id,
                         'sort_key': id_2
                        },
                    UpdateExpression=f"set {attribute} = :val",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ":val": {"N": f"{value}"}
                        },
                    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
                )
```

I expected it to be like

```
{
  "total": 5,
  "time": 80,
  "users": 1,
  "app_id": "PRODUCT_ID",
  "sort_key": "abcde"
}
```

However, it saves like this

```
{
  "total": {
    "N": "5"
  },
  "time": {
    "N": "80"
  },
  "users": {
    "N": "1"
  },
  "app_id": "PRODUCT_ID",
  "sort_key": "abcde"
}
```

If I just do

```
ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ":val": value
                        },
```

Python json serialization fails

How can I save it with in Number data type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the DynamoDB "raw" object syntax, the "N" is telling you the type of it (Number in this case) and the value next to it serialized (It needs to be serialized since it's coming from a http request)

What you can do is use boto3's high level Table object that will automatically convert it for you. But it's just a helper, in the end it will be stored exactly the same.

Reference : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#table

It will automatically convert Python types to DynamoDB types, and you also don't need to use "ExpressionAttributeValues", there's a more pythonic syntax :

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table1')
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'partition_key': id,
        'sort_key' : id_2
    },
    AttributeUpdates={
        'attribute': {
            'Value': value,
            'Action': 'DELETE'
        }
    }
)
```